# Is there a word that means an action that is the death of an idea?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something like the word 'antithesis', however instead of just meaning 'this is the opposite of that' I thought there was a word that meant 'doing this signals the death of this'.

I thought there was a word to describe this, but nothing comes to mind.

The meaning behind the phrase I'm thinking of is roughly 'if I accept to do this, it is the death of the purpose of my job'.

Comment: Do you require a word or longer expression? It's not clear.

Comment: Are you talking about something like a [Catch-22](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/catch-22)?

Comment: You might use the prefix like "counter" as in "counter-intuitive"  or "counter-productive"

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

**The final nail in the coffin**

> an event that causes the failure of something that had already started to fail:
> This latest evidence could be the final nail in the coffin for Jackson's case.

[Cambridge Dictionary]

Or perhaps, the words below sound more appropriate in the context you've provided  (Apologies, I read the example you have provided after giving my first answer).

**negate**

> to cause to be ineffective or invalid
> Alcohol can negate the effects of some medicines.

**Thwart**

> to oppose successfully : defeat the hopes or aspirations of

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

The compound noun **death knell** may be used:

> *death knell* [noun]
>
> a harbinger of the end, death, or destruction of something.

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/death-knell)] [usually used figuratively]

> - Online delivery is not the death knell for record companies.

From the Cambridge English Corpus [[via Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/death-knell)]

Answer (score 1):

> if I accept doing this, it is **the kiss of death** for the purpose of my job'.

OED at "Kiss"

> **6a.   kiss of death**  n.  [ < the association with the kiss of betrayal given to Jesus by Judas in the Garden of Gethsemane (Matthew xxvi. 48–50)] **a seemingly kind or well-intentioned action, look, association, etc., which brings disastrous consequences.**
>
> 1948   ‘N. Shute’ No Highway iv. 113   *I told you that he'd put the kiss of death on it.*
>
> 1960   Guardian 10 Dec. 5/1   *Let us hope that the critics' approval does not, at the box-office, prove a kiss of death.*
>
> 1970   New Scientist 27 Aug. 405/1   *In some countries state participation is essential for a scientific programme, in others it often seems the kiss of death.*

Answer (score 1):

> If I accept doing this, it **marks the end** of my job.

**mark the end** (of something) is a frequent collocation.

**mark** (v.)

> SIGNALIZE
>
> *This year marks our 50th anniversary* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mark)

> Be an indication of (a significant occasion, stage, or development)
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mark)

> Exile **marked the end** of any reference to the lost tribes in biblical
> texts. *Times, Sunday Times* (2010)
>
> It is, therefore, thought probable that the rejection of the present
> overtures will not by any means **mark the end** of the enemy peace
> offensive.
> *Times, Sunday Times* (2018)
>
> It is, therefore, thought probable that the rejection of the present
> overtures will not by any means **mark the end** of the enemy peace
> offensive.
> *Times, Sunday Times* (2018) [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/e)

---

> Loewe became a shipboard pianist until the end of Prohibition **marked
> the end of his job**. [Ken Bloom; *Broadway: An Encyclopedia*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Broadway/Ib2awFyFUKoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22marked%20the%20end%20of%20his%20job%22&pg=PT297&printsec=frontcover)
> (2013)
>
> ...Cowly took a salary cut, was kept out of the office, and asked to
> send in a weekly review from Sherman. Though he continue to contribute
> essays and reviews to the *New Republic*, this effectively **marked
> the end of his job** there. [K. Burke et al.; *The Selected
> Correspondence of Kenneth Burke and Malcom Cowley*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Selected_Correspondence_of_Kenneth_B/OOYTrndHblgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22marked%20the%20end%20of%20his%20job%22&pg=PA155&printsec=frontcover)